# (VPS Cloud) Site goes down, htacces modified, i think due to high traffic

Tags: php, .htaccess, vps, wordpress

i have a cloud vps at ovh having 8GB of ram, a 6 vCores processor and installed  Parallels Plesk 12 on Ubuntu 14.04 (64 bits)
I have more than 10 sites in there but only 2 have traffic
From histats:
Site 1: Users online : 167 visitors today : 14,591
Site 2: Users online : 182 visitors today : 7,140

I think that to much traffic is causing my htaccess file to get modified with a 's' character in the end causing a 500 server error
I think traffic is the fault as same happened to me on godaddy shared hosting, they do the same
But i dont understand, isnt that vps more than enough to handle such traffic? Why is this happening to me, please help as i dont know where to look
Also.. Wordpress is installed on my sites

This is a screenshot from my vps stats:

[image]

Contents of the `.htaccess` file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress and then
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress s
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand that question. How is the `.htaccess` file modified? Do you have an example for that? You really mean that high load modifies files? Please also check/post the error log of the Apache httpd. This should contain the reason, why it emits an error.

Comment: this was my htaccess  
# BEGIN WordPress  
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>  
RewriteEngine On  
RewriteBase /  
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]  
</IfModule>
  
# END WordPress 
  
and then  
# BEGIN WordPress  
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>  
RewriteEngine On  
RewriteBase /  
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]  
</IfModule>  
  
# END WordPress  
s

Comment: this is a part of apache error log http://pastebin.com/QuqxuauT @StephenKing

Comment: you need Varnish cache...

Comment: this is my error log file at the time it happened http://pastebin.com/XVrXKTrf @StephenKing

Comment: So just to verify once more: Your `.htaccess` file on the server is being modified? Can you check that by the last modification time? I would then assume that your WP installation is getting hacked.

Comment: no it is not getting hacked, it is just some script trying to keep server up by shutting heavy site down, it adds a 's' at end making htaccess broken

Comment: You answer it yourself. You have a script knowingly installed which willingly breaks the htaccess file and causes the site to crash. IMHO that is a dumb script and I'd remove it. It is 'solving' a problem in a very bad way. To keep your server up under load, you should look in to a better performant web stack. You could for example install WordFence Falcon for full page caching. Or swap Apache with NginX, maybe add Varnish or CloudFlare. You can swap MySQL with Percona, add some DB Query caching etc. There is loads you can do.

Answer (score 1):

Now we know your htaccess damage is, weirdly, intentional, here some suggestions towards a true solution:

1. Your webserver is badly configured and causes many many error log writes. This in itself causes unnecessary IO disk writes and should be fixed. Fix all those errors (Especially around SSL) and your server will already be more capable. Or suppress error writing.
2. You run WordPress on those sites. There are many ways to get WordPress performing better under load. Some ideas:

   a. Some of the traffic spikes may be malicious. Plugins such as WordFence can throttle this. Or use ipTables, or Fail2Ban to ensure your server keeps performing. Examine the traffic and see whether you can block some of it before it reaches Apache/PHP.

   b. A lean, well-optimized page is easier to serve. Check Google Page Speed Ingights, WebPageTst.org, GTMetrix etc. for clues on optimizing your site. GZip and Browser Cache especially can have huge impacts on server load.

   c. Caching data makes things easier to server. You can cache MySQL DB Queries for example or use plugins such as W3 Total Cache to cache objects to disk. Or use WordFence Falcon Engine to enable full page cache.

   d. Through for example W3 Total Cache, you can use CDN to offload some requests, or even CloudFlare which can take over your site entirely when it's unresponsive.

   e. Many sysadmins find NginX performs better under duress than Apache. Consider tweaking your web stack from say Apache/MySQL to NginX/Percona.

   f. Profile your WordPress install(s) and remove any badly performing plugins. GoDaddy has a profiler plugin which can tell you the worst offenders. I see many WordPress sites with a bad mix of terrible plugins hogging system resources.